# Are "Is A based on a true story?" questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

Is there anything wrong with asking if a film is based on a true story if it isn't apparently obvious either way?

Comment: As i know, there is no problem in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not see why this would be off-topic.

Comment: As i expected .